# Combo box automatically assigns a value, when not wanted. C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

I'm having this issue with ComboBox controls. I select a value for the combo box (Already pre-setted) and it AUTOMATICALLY assigns the same value to another ComboBox next to it. Despite their data source is the same List, I want to select two different values (from that same list) for those two combo boxes.

```
cmbEmpresas.DataSource = Empresa.listaDeEmpresas;
cmbEmpresas.DisplayMember = "NombreEmpresa"; //This works OK


cmbLlegada.DataSource = Locacion.listaDeLocaciones;
cmbLlegada.DisplayMember = "Ciudad";

//These two represent a starting and arriving location for a trip
//they both have objects of the type "Locación"


cmbSalida.DataSource = Locacion.listaDeLocaciones;
cmbSalida.DisplayMember = "Ciudad";
```

[image: FORM'S IMAGE]

As it is shown in the previous image, both `cmbLlegada` and `cmbSalida` have the same value, I did not want this to happen, I just selected `cmbSalida`'s value and it automatically changed `cmbLlegada`'s value.

Comment: If the datasource is the same, controls bound to it will act the same. To make them independent, use some `DataView`s built from the same datasource

Comment: As the comment above ^^^. You can clone your data source

Comment: Oh... Can tyou pass the code of that? haha just as reference